# Qual a diferença entre os tipos de projetos WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

Quais as diferenças entre os vários tipos de projeto de WCF:

- WCF Service Library;
- WCF Service Application;
- WCF Workflow Service Application;
- Syndication Service Library;

Answer (score 1):

Grosso modo:

`WCF Service Application`

Cria uma aplicação WCF pré-configurada a ser hospedada no IIS.

`WCF Service Library`

Cria uma aplicação WCF que será adicionada como referência para uso em outro projeto e você deve configurar sua hospedagem. É um componente compilado que pode ser utilizado por outras aplicações como um serviço Web, Console ou Windows.

Encontrei um [**artigo**](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Developing-a-WCF-Service-Library-and-Hosting-it-as-WCF-Web-Service-Using-VS2K8/) (conteúdo em inglês) que descreve informações mais detalhadas sobre a diferença entre *WCF Service Application* e *WCF Service Library*. 
Os demais eu ainda não utilizei, dê uma olhada nos links (conteúdo em inglês) para ver se te ajuda:

`WCF Workflow Service Application`

Cria uma aplicação WCF baseada em *WorkFlows*. Cenário onde um serviço depende de outros serviços externos em que essas chamadas podem ser de longa duração ([LinqRef1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456797(v=vs.110).aspx) / [LinqRef2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432975(v%3Dvs.110).aspx)).

`Syndication Service Library`

Fornece suporte para expor os *syndication feeds* através de um serviço WCF. 
Por exemplo, você possui um banco de dados de bugs que você deseja expor através de [***feeds***](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feed). Você pode criar um serviço WCF que expõe um método chamado BugsDaAplicacao. Este método possui um parâmetro que especifica o endereço de e-mail da pessoa que receberá as informações. Um cliente do seu serviço pode utilizar o seguinte URL para chamar a operação: `http://server/bugs/bugsDaAplicacao?user=fulano` ([LinqRef1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412202(v=vs.110).aspx) / [LinqRef2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412195(v=vs.110).aspx)).